# Covid API, how to get only id

Tags: node.js, https, discord.js

I am making a discord bot that parses canada's covid API, but I only want the id (see JSON example below:)

```
{
      id: 797158,
      province: 'QC',
      city: 'Pending',
      age: 'Pending',
      travel_history: 'Pending',
      confirmed_presumptive: 'CONFIRMED',
      source: 'https://www.quebec.ca/sante/problemes-de-sante/a-z/coronavirus-2019/situation-coronavirus-quebec/',
      date: '2021-02-03 09:05:13',
      hr_uid: null
    }
```

I am now wondering how only get the "id" part of the JSON response, here is my code:

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://api.covid19tracker.ca/cases?province=qc', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been received.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

If someone could also tell me how to do a get request to the api each 5 minutes, then compare the last `"id"` from the last request, I would like that.

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward - what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I got stuck at the setInterval part, I can't figure out how to set it up. I also cannot figure out how to only get the first "id" of the response I get, neither do I know how I could compare them. Sorry if I am asking for too much, I am a beginner and I don't really know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the id from the response data using "JSON.parse(data).id". As for running the request every 5 minutes you can use the setInterval function for that see more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: I get this error:

undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: yes you are right i missed the parse call, try now i updated the answer

Comment: Sorry for bothergin, but it only returns undefined. Sorry again..